# How can I concurrently upload files using the winscpnet.dll

Tags: powershell, concurrency, sftp, winscp, winscp-net

How can I concurrently upload files using the winscpnet.dll.  I would like to set the winscp.exe instances that can run concurrently to x number of winscp.exe instances using a script or c#.

Other threads have mentioned the documentation in the link below but that code will look at the remote server and download all the files in x session concurrently using session.GetFiles 
https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_example_parallel_transfers#powershell

I am looking to do similar but would like to upload files from a directory using session.PutFiles.

There is a function built into the winscpnet.dll code that will enumerate the remote directory but nothing to do something for the opposite.  Loop through a local directory and start five instances of winscp.exe and when they are done do that until all the files are completed there session.Putfiles transfer.

The reason this is important is that uploading them one at a time to the remote sftp server takes significantly longer then doing them concurrently.

Answer (score 1):

- There's no API in WinSCP .NET assembly for enumeration local files, as the that has nothing to with the remote connection.

  There's actually an API for this in PowerShell, the [`Get-ChildItem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem).
- Other than that, the code will be pretty much the same as the download code (except for obvious differences like using [`Session.PutFiles`](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_session_putfiles), instead of `Session.GetFiles`).

The article, that you referenced, now includes a full code for [upload in parallel connections over SFTP protocol in C#](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_example_parallel_transfers#upload_csharp).

Answer (score 1):

If you still need it, here we go.

```
#Powershell script to upload files from a local dire 
param ( 
$sessionUrl = "sftp://tester:password;fingerprint=ssh-rsa 2048 ba:5d:a4:1b:0a:73:30:cf:90:dd:e3:ef:6c:9e:1d:94@localhost", 
$remotePath = "/", 
$localPath = "C:\Users\your\test\upload", 
$batches = 3 
) 

#Upload data to local Rebex Tiny SFTP 

try 
{ 
    # Load WinSCP .NET assembly 
    $dllPath = (Join-Path $PSScriptRoot "WinSCPnet.dll") 
    # Load WinSCP .NET assembly 
    Add-Type -Path $dllPath 

    $started = Get-Date 

    # Build list of local files and sort them from larges to smallest 
    $files = Get-ChildItem $localPath | Sort-Object Length -Descending 

    # Calculate total size of all files 
    $total = ($files | Measure-Object -Property Length -Sum).Sum 

    # And batch size 
    $batch = [int]($total / $batches) 

    Write-Host ("Will upload {0} files totaling {1} bytes in {2} parallel batches, {3} bytes on average in each" -f $files.Count, $total, $batches, $batch) 

    $start = 0 
    $sum = 0 
    $no = 0 

    for ($i = 0; $i -lt $files.Count; $i++) 
    { 
        $sum += $files[$i].Length 

        # Found enough files for the next batch 
        if (($sum -ge $batch) -or ($i -eq $files.Count - 1)) 
        { 
            Write-Host ("Starting batch {0} to upload {1} files totaling {2}" -f $no, ($i - $start + 1), $sum) 

            $fileList = $files[$start..$i] -join ";" 

            # Start the background job for the batch 
            Start-Job -Name "Batch $no" -ArgumentList $dllPath, $sessionUrl, $localPath, $remotePath, $no, $fileList { 
                param ( 
                    [Parameter(Position = 0)] 
                    $dllPath, 
                    [Parameter(Position = 1)] 
                    $sessionUrl, 
                    [Parameter(Position = 2)] 
                    $localPath, 
                    [Parameter(Position = 3)] 
                    $remotePath, 
                    [Parameter(Position = 4)] 
                    $no, 
                    [Parameter(Position = 5)] 
                    $fileList 
                ) 

                try 
                { 
                    Write-Host ("Starting batch {0}" -f $no) 

                    # Load WinSCP .NET assembly. 
                    # Need to use an absolute path as the Job is started from user's documents folder. 
                    Add-Type -Path $dllPath 

                    # Setup session options 
                    $sessionOptions = New-Object WinSCP.SessionOptions 
                    $sessionOptions.ParseUrl($sessionUrl) 

                    try 
                    { 
                        Write-Host ("Connecting batch {0}..." -f $no) 
                        $session = New-Object WinSCP.Session 

                        $session.Open($sessionOptions) 

                        $files = $fileList -split ";" 

                        # Upload the files selected for this batch 
                        foreach ($file in $files) 
                        { 
                            $localFilePath = "$localPath\$file" 
                            $remoteFilePath = "$remotePath/$file" 
                            Write-Host "Uploading $localFilePath to $remoteFilePath in $no" 

                            $session.PutFiles($session.EscapeFileMask($localFilePath), $remoteFilePath).Check() 
                        } 
                    } 
                    finally 
                    { 
                        # Disconnect, clean up 
                        $session.Dispose() 
                    } 

                    Write-Host ("Batch {0} done" -f $no) 
                } 
                catch [Exception] 
                { 
                    Write-Host $_.Exception.Message 
                    exit 1 
                } 
            } | Out-Null 

            # Reset for the next batch 
            $no++ 
            $sum = 0 
            $start = $i + 1 
        } 
    } 

    Write-Host "Waiting for batches to complete" 
    Get-Job | Receive-Job -Wait 

    Write-Host "Done" 

    $ended = Get-Date 
    Write-Host ("Took {0}" -f (New-TimeSpan -Start $started -End $ended)) 

    exit 0 
} 
catch [Exception] 
{ 
    Write-Host $_.Exception.Message 
    exit 1 
}
```